# Trying open a project made with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a project with Android Studio on Linux, works fine. Now, I'm trying open this project on Windows but when I try open throws an exception.

How could I solve it ?

**Exception**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        C:\desenvolvimento\SDK\sdk\build-tools\21.0.0\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\desenvolvimento\SDK\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar -M C:\Users\fernando\AndroidstudioProjects\GuiaStore\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\fernando\AndroidstudioProjects\GuiaStore\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Users\fernando\AndroidstudioProjects\GuiaStore\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\fernando\AndroidstudioProjects\GuiaStore\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\fernando\AndroidstudioProjects\GuiaStore\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package br.com.williarts.guiastore -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\fernando\AndroidstudioProjects\GuiaStore\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
    Error Code:
        -1073741819
```

Comment: Could you try using build tools 21.0.2 in Windows?

Comment: very nice @PatrickLC, I did change `buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"` to `buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"` and works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great news! I had a similar issue in Windows and remember that changing the buildToolsVersion was the way to fix it. :)

Comment: nice... @PatrickLC could you create an answer to check with V ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own experience: working with an existence project in Android Studio on Windows using build tools "21.0.0", it results on the published error.

Changing the build tools to "21.0.2" fixed the issue.